# String that is initialized lazily in Python

Tags: python, string, lazy-evaluation

I figured out that with deriving from `str` and overwriting `__new__` you can overwrite strings. Do you know any magic that would create a lazily initialized string?
Therefore

```
def f(a, b):
    print("f called")
    return a+b

s=f("a", "b")
print("Starting")
print(s)
```

how can I add a decorator to the function `f` such that this function is executed only *after* "Starting" was printed (basically on first access)? Seems tricky... :)

I can do it when objects are returned, because there I intercept attribute access. However, string doesn't use attribute access?

Comment: You could make the `__add__` method lazy. If you want to make `f` lazy, then why not have it return a thunk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be simpler ways of doing what you want --
However, I once wrote  a generic "lazy decorator" for generic functions that does exactly what you are asking for -- perceive it is  more complicated exactly because it would work for almost any kind of object returned by the functions.

The basic idea is: for a given exiting object, Python does not actually "use" its value but for callingone of the "dunder' (magic double "__" ) methods in the object's class -
be it for representing it ( calls either `__repr__  __str__ __unicode__`) getting attributes from it, making calls, usiogn it as an operator in an arithmetic operation and so on.

So, this decorator, when the function is called, basically stores the parameters and wait for any of these magic methods to be called, whereupon it does make the originall call and caches the return value -

The soruce code is here:

https://github.com/jsbueno/metapython/blob/main/lazy_decorator.py

Comment: Maybe that will help. However, I couldn't execute your script as shown on the webpage due to "func_closure=func.func_closure; AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'func_closure'". Any ideas? Moreover, will your script also work if you remove the print("bla ...") statement?

Comment: Are you using Python 3.x?  func_closure should exist in Python 2 - it will work as `__closure__` but there are other possible incompatibilities of this code with python3

Comment: Thanks. It works now :) I have to go through it, but that might be exactly what I need. Is there a method to avoid listing `data_model_methods` manually?

Comment: @Gerenuk: it is possible to avoid the manual listing if you know by advance the type of object that will be returned by the decorated function - for example, for strings, just use the list returned by str.__dict__.keys() instead of the manual listing.

Comment: bitbucket is now 404

Comment: Indeed. Atlassian simply killed-out all mercurial repos back in Jul-2020.  I've just re-uploaded the snippet collection were this example lives into github.

Answer (score 3):

The attributes you're looking for are `__str__()`, `__repr__()`, and `__unicode__()`.

Comment: Thanks. It goes into the right direction. I suppose for my lazy evaluation I need to find a way to change the internal value of my user string inside the __str__ function (i.e. when it is first access and thus loaded). Is there a way to write the string value?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `LazyString` class from [stringlike](https://pypi.org/project/stringlike/), like this

```
from stringlike.lazy import LazyString

def f(a, b):
    print("f called")
    return a+b

s = LazyString(lambda: f("a", "b"))
print("Starting")
print(s)
```